# A theorem valid for closed and bounded intervals is also valid for interval of any kind?

Tags: calculus

I've a question on intervals.

Consider  this situation: a theorem is valid for intervals $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ **closed and bounded**

Can I say that the theorem is valid for a interval $J\subset \mathbb{R}$ **of any kind** since it can be valid in any subinterval of $J$ that is closed and bounded?

I mean if I take two elements of $J$, $x_1<x_2$, then I can consider the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ and use the theorem there. Since I took two generic elements of $J$ can I conclude that the theorem is valid for all the elements in $J$ and therefore for $J$?

To make it more clear, consider this example.

I want to show that, considered $f$ a function that is differentiable (and so continuous) in a interval $J$ **of any kind**,

$f'(x)\geq 0 \implies $ $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Since I want to use the mean value theorem, which can be used only for functions continuous in **closed and bounded** intervals $I$, can I consider a generic subinterval of $J$ closed and bounded, prove the fact and than conclude that it is valid for all $J$?

Thanks in advice for your help

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$ for $0\le x\le 1$, and let $f(0)=17$. Then $f'(x)\gt 0$ for all $x$ in the interval $(0,1)$ but $f(x)$ is not an increasing function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: For a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval $I$, $\exists$ $M$ such that $f(x)<M$ $\forall x\in I$.  That's a theorem that holds for closed and bounded intervals.  But it's not true for any kind of interval.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for the answer, but in that case, the mean value theorem can't be used because $f$ is not continuous in a bounded and closed interval. What I meant was to consider a generic interval $[x_1,x_2] \mid x_1 \in (0,1) , x_2\in (0,1)$ in order to prove that the theorem is valid in $(0,1)$, not in $[0,1]$ (of course there it can't be valid)

Comment: Your question is not clear. The question in the title has an immediate, silly counterexample. Given a closed and bounded interval $I=[a,b]$ we have that "$I$ is closed and bounded" is a theorem. But certainly this doesn't imply that every interval is closed and bounded, for example $(a,b)$ is not.

Comment: Theorem: If  $f:R\to R$ is continuous and if $J$ is a closed bounded interval then either (i) $J=\phi$ or (ii) $\max \{f(x) :x\in J\}$  exists. This not applicable to all intervals, For  example if $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in R$, and  $J=[0,1)$.